# "Liked" posts redirect to application.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a pretty standard implementation of the facebook 'Like' plug-in - [example post](http://www.swolept.com/posts/plantar-fasciitis-complete-treatment-guide).

The problem is that when the like button is pressed, and comment is added the link on my profile always points to a broken link.

```
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=193048140809145
```

### Here's what the shared post looks like

[image]

### Wrong Link goes to

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. Please subscribe to the bug report on facebook to give it a higher priority: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/490260747715286